# Write a function that returns the number of zeros in a given array?

Tags: javascript

So I have to write a function the counts the number of zeros in an array

so far all I have is

```
numberOfZeros= function(arry) {
    if(!(Object.prototype.toString.call(arry) === '[object Array]')){
        arry.toString();
    }
}
```

then I'm stuck or not even sure if I going about it in the write way

but the number of zeros for example should be 2 in numberOfZeros([4, 0, false, 5, 0]):

Comment: What made you think your code would count the number of zeros?

Comment: By the way, what do you consider to be a zero: `+0`, `-0`, or both?

Comment: I know I can count things in string so I thought maybe converting to string would help. I honestly do NOT understand how to answer this question.

Comment: Good question.  Voted it up.

Answer (score 5):

You need to `.filter()` for all values of `0` and then just read the `.length` of the outcome.

```
return arry.filter(v => v === 0).length;
```

Comment: Arrow notation is _ES6_, if you plan to use this answer please check your environment supports it.

Comment: Welcome to 2015. Every browser supports Arrow functions by now.

Comment: @jAndy https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/ ie10 does not, android 5.0's default browser does not. Welcome to 2015.

Comment: IE11 does not either. Looking along that table you'll see some other notable exceptions are iOS+Android stock and Safari

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```
numberOfZeros = function (arry) {
    var c = 0;
    for (var k in arry) {
        if (arry[k] === 0 && arry[k] === parseInt(arry[k], 10)) {
            c += 1;
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

Comment: numberOfZeros([4, 0, false, 5, 0]): returns 1 not 2

Comment: Edited, should be okay now !

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the elements and check if they are zero:

```
var n = 0;
for(var item of array)
  if(item === 0) // Both +0 and -0
    ++n;
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution :

```js
var numberOfZeros = function(arry) {
  var i = 0;
  arry.forEach(function(v) {
    if (v === 0) i++;
  });
  return i;
}


var count = numberOfZeros([4, 0, false, 5, 0]);

alert( count );
```

Answer (score 0):

Well You could use this approach by making a new array and pushing all of the zeros in the main array inside the new array and just getting the `.length` of the new array.

---

```
function numberOfZeros(array) {
    var zeros = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i ++){
        if(array[i] === 0) {
            zeros.push(array[i]);
        }
    }
    console.log(zeros.length);
}

numberOfZeros([4, 0, false, 5, 0]);
```

---

**JSFIDDLE - https://jsfiddle.net/ToreanJoel/3j2zpgnm/**